# salesforce integration with paypal(i am getting a failure message )

Tags: apex, visualforce, paypal

### Salesforce integration with paypal

1. Done the integration of salesforce with paypal by apex class PaypalProcessor
2. I have created a vf page containing fields of custom object paypal_payment and it calls apex class approvedPaypalController.

But i am getting the failure msg...i have attached the code below.
please let me know where i am going wrong.

### Apex class paypalprocessor:

```
public class PaypalProcessor {

    /*
     *  The entry point of the processor, call from page controller, or schedule from trigger with @future annotation
     */
    public Boolean processNewPayments() {
        List<Paypal_Payment__c> paymentBatch = [SELECT Id, Name, Paypal_email__c, Paypal_amount__c,
                                            CurrencyIsoCode__c, Paypal_payment_date__c
                                            FROM Paypal_Payment__c
                                            WHERE Paypal_status__c = 'unpaid' LIMIT 250];

        Boolean success = processSOAPPayments(paymentBatch);

        return success;
    }

    /*
     * This function collects a HTTPRequest object and sends it to PayPal
     * It then interprets the response, updates the payments as appropriate and returns success boolean.
     *
     * Param: A list of custom payment records as provided by processNewPayments
     * Returns: A boolean, whose value is dependent on the response from PayPal
     */
    public static Boolean processSOAPPayments(List<Paypal_Payment__c> paymentBatch) {

        String result;
        String error = '';

        Http http = new Http();

        HttpResponse response;

        try {
            // If this method is called in a testing context, then respond with a sample output.
            // This is necessary as http requests cannot be sent from test methods.
            if(Test.isRunningTest()) {
                // If a test is being run, get the response from the page parameters
                response = new HttpResponse();
                response.setBody(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('SOAPResponse'));
            } else {
                HttpRequest req = generateRequest(paymentBatch);
                response        = http.send(req);
            }

            // Digest the response:
            String rawResponse = response.getBody();

            XmlStreamReader reader = response.getXmlStreamReader();

            // Navigate through the response
            while(reader.hasNext())
            {
                if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.START_ELEMENT)
                {
                    // Find the ACK element
                    if (reader.getLocalName() == 'Ack')
                    {
                        reader.next();
                        if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.characters)
                        {
                            result = reader.getText();
                        }
                    }
                    // Find any error messages
                    if (reader.getLocalName() == 'LongMessage')
                    {
                        reader.next();
                        if (reader.getEventType() == XmlTag.characters)
                        {
                            error = reader.getText();
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.next();
            }

            // If the result is success, mark the payments as 'Sent' and log the time against them.
            if (result.equals('Success'))
            { 
                Datetime paidTime = Datetime.now();

                for (Paypal_Payment__c payment: paymentBatch)
                {
                    payment.Paypal_payment_date__c  = paidTime;
                    payment.Paypal_status__c        = 'sent';
                }

                update paymentBatch;

                return true;
            } else {
                // If the result ISN'T success, sort out a useful message
                system.debug('Failed for ' + error);
            }
        } catch (Calloutexception e) {
            system.debug(e.getMessage());
        }

        // If we did not return "True" above, the process must have failed
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * This function generates the HttpRequest object, and requires your PayPal API credentials to do so.
     * Params: The list of custom payment records to process
     * Returns: A fully populated HttpRequest object
     */
    public static HttpRequest generateRequest(List<Paypal_Payment__c> paymentBatch) {

        // Set the PayPal credentials from your PayPal account API settings page
        String purl = 'sandbox.paypal.com';
        String user = '';
        String pass = '';
        String sign = '';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

        // SOAP API URL
        String url = 'https://api-3t.' + purl + '/2.0';

        // Have the XML message generated
        String soapRequestBody = generateMsgBody(paymentBatch, user, pass, sign);

        // Set the headers
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-length', soapRequestBody.length().format());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setBody(soapRequestBody); 
        req.setHeader('Host','api-aa.' + purl);
        // Increase the timeout header to the max
        req.setTimeout(60000);

        return req;
    }

    /*
     * This function builds the actual XML body string for the HTTP request.
     * Params: The list of payment records to insert.
     *         The PayPal API username, password and signiture
     * Returns: An XML formatted string
     */
    public static String generateMsgBody(List<Paypal_Payment__c> paymentBatch, String user, String pass, String sign)
    {
        // Build the request string. There are java/php/asp APIs for this, but in Apex, I have done it by hand.
        String soapRequestBody;
        soapRequestBody  = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\' xmlns:xsi=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\' xmlns:xsd=\'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\'>';
        soapRequestBody += '<soap:Header><RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
        soapRequestBody += '<Username>' + user + '</Username><ebl:Password xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">' + pass + '</ebl:Password><Signature>' + sign + '</Signature>';
        soapRequestBody += '</Credentials></RequesterCredentials></soap:Header>';
        soapRequestBody += '<soap:Body>';
        soapRequestBody += '<MassPayReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">';
        soapRequestBody += '<MassPayRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
        soapRequestBody += '<Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">84.00</Version>';
        soapRequestBody += '<EmailSubject xsi:type="xs:string">Payment from Greenlight</EmailSubject>';
        soapRequestBody += '<ReceiverType recieverinfocode="EmailAddress"/>';
        // Iterate through the payment record list and insert their details.
        for(Paypal_Payment__c paymentObj: paymentBatch)
        {
            soapRequestBody += '<MassPayItem xsi:type="ebl:MassPayItemType">';
            soapRequestBody += '<ReceiverEmail>' + paymentObj.Paypal_email__c + '</ReceiverEmail>';
            soapRequestBody += '<Amount currencyID="' + paymentObj.CurrencyIsoCode__c + '">' + paymentObj.Paypal_amount__c + '</Amount>';
            soapRequestBody += '<UniqueId>' + paymentObj.Id + '</UniqueId>';
            soapRequestBody += '<Note>Payment Ref: ' + paymentObj.Name + '</Note>';
            soapRequestBody += '</MassPayItem>';

        }
        soapRequestBody += '</MassPayRequest></MassPayReq>';
        soapRequestBody += '</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

        return soapRequestBody;
    }
}
```

### Apex class called by vf :

```
public class approvedPaypalController {

    public approvedPaypalController() {
        payPalApproved();
    }

    public List<Paypal_Payment__c> paypalApprovedList { get; set; }

    public void payPalApproved() {
        paypalApprovedList = new List<Paypal_Payment__c>();
        paypalApprovedList = [SELECT id, Paypal_email__c, paypal_amount__c, paypal_status__c FROM Paypal_Payment__c LIMIT 250 FOR UPDATE];
    }

    public void pay() {
        // This is the killer method call:
        if(makePayment())
        {
            for(Paypal_Payment__c pp: paypalApprovedList)
            {
                if(pp.paypal_status__c == 'Unpaid') {
                    pp.paypal_status__c = 'Sent';
                }
            }
            update(paypalApprovedList);
        } 
    }

    public boolean makePayment() {
        PaypalProcessor p = new PaypalProcessor();
        boolean payResult;
        if(Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            payResult= true;   
        }
        else
        {
            payResult = p.processNewPayments();
        }
        if(payResult)
        {
            apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Success'));
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Failure'));
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

### Visualforce page code :

```
<apex:page controller="approvedPaypalController">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Send Payments to PayPal"/>
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Pay out" action="{!pay}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Current payment records" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!paypalApprovedList}" var="payment"> 
                    <apex:column value="{!payment.Paypal_Email__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!payment.Paypal_Status__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!payment.Paypal_Amount__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The credentials in your code look like they are your actual credentials. I suggest changing your passwords if this is the case.

Comment: 2 cheers to you @BarCotter

Comment: so what is the problem...help me out

Comment: What is "the failure msg" - is that a Salesforce error, paypal error etc?  You need to tell us which area is causing the problem.

Comment: it is the message created in  approvedpaypalcontroller class  called by vf page which i have posted .The method is makepayment() which makes this message when transaction is not successful.

Comment: You have a `system.debug(e.getMessage());` in the code - have you checked the debug log for that message? You should also output the `rawResponse` to the debug log and the HTTP status returned. While this might solve your current problem, you should refactor your `PaypalProcessor` code to return a meaningful error message that is then presented via the `ApexPages.Message`; returning a boolean provides nothing useful to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: i am getting a error msg in debug log       "03:00:03.297 (1297046465)|USER_DEBUG|[93]|DEBUG|Failed for --------------Currency is not supported"

Comment: i have kept currencies of all acount in paypal sandbox as us..but  still the problem persists

Comment: please help me out why am i getting this currency not supported error...